# Use of more of this product

Tags: adjectives

> Do not use more of this product than is recommended on the label.

What does '' more of '' mean in this sentence ? Would it be the same structure if I would say;

> Will you need more of this product in the future?

Answer (score 1):

"More" means "*a greater or additional amount or degree*". It can be used *comparatively* by saying "*more than*"

In your first example, it is being used comparatively:

> Do not use **more** of this product **than is recommended on the label**.

It means that there is a prescribed, or recommended amount of a product that should be used, and the statement is advising you not to exceed this.

In your second example, there is no use of "than", so it is *not* comparative:

> Will you need more of this product in the future?

When the product is used up, you can get more... and more... and more... there is no limit implied with this usage.